# Getting a "type" column from each table in query

Tags: mysql

Let's assume I have 3 tables: videos, books, albums and I would like a query that gives me the 3 latest entries in each table, along with a column "media_type" valued Video, Book, or Album, accordingly.

I know how to get the 3 latest entries from each table, but how do I create the temporary column?

Comment: You mean something like `SELECT b.*, 'books' as table_name FROM books b`?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
(SELECT id, name, 'Book' AS media_type
FROM books
LIMIT 0,3) 

UNION ALL 

(SELECT id, name, 'Video' AS media_type
FROM videos
LIMIT 0,3)

UNION ALL

(SELECT id, name, 'Album' AS media_type
FROM albums
LIMIT 0,3);
```

I don't know if you need any particular ordering or not.  According to the docs, UNION produces an unordered set of rows.  You should be able to add an ORDER BY after the last SELECT, outside the parentheses.

Comment: There is no need to put each select of a UNION into parentheses.

Comment: When I tested it, without the parentheses the LIMIT was only applying to the entire set.  I was only getting 3 rows returned--the books.  I'm running an older version (5.0.96), perhaps that behavior has changed.